# python concurrent.futures future function return value issue

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

i am using concurrent.futures ThreadPoolExecutor to exceute multi-ping test. here is script:

```
import concurrent.futures
import os

#HOST IP in my network
ip_add_list = ['192.168.1.200', '192.168.1.201', '192.168.1.202', 
                '192.168.1.205', '192.168.1.208', '10.1.1.1']

#run ping command in windows
def ping_result(ip,command):


    result = os.system(command +" " + ip + " -n 1")

    if result ==0:
        ping_re = 'ping successful'
    else:
        ping_re = 'ping failed'
    return ping_re
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:    
    future_result ={executor.submit(ping_result, list, 'ping'): list for list in ip_add_list } 
    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_result):      
        ip  = future_result[f]
        print (ip)
        #data = future_result[f]
        print (ip)
        print (data)
```

I can get correct resutl with this script and the furture_result type is Dict

when i tried to replace this line to for loop as below:

```
future_result ={executor.submit(ping_result, list, 'ping'): list for list in ip_add_list }
```

to be replaced by:

```
future_result = {}
for list in ip_add_list:
    future_result = {executor.submit(ping_result, list, 'ping')}
```

I got the error message"TypeError: 'set' object is not subscriptable" and i found if i don't pre-define future_result as Dict, the executor.submit will return a set. How can i fix this error with for loop command.

Comment: `executor.submit()` is not returning a set, *you're* making a set out of its return value (by enclosing it in curly braces).  And you're overwriting `future_result` with that set each time, so you end up with only a single result.  Your original code was fine, but if you really want to change it to a `for` loop the body would be something like `future_result[executor.submit(ping_result, list, 'ping')] = list`.

Comment: @jasonharper. sorry, maybe i did not expalin it clearly. with original code, the executor.submit() return a Dict, but for for loop, it return set, not Dict even though i also have {} . I need it also return Dict for for loop. so i can run below command correctly to get ip and data.

Comment: It doesn't matter what it returned, the curly braces you put around the expression are turning it into a set.

Comment: how can i make it return as Dict, not set for for loop. i am new to python.

Comment: what is the differences between orignal config and for loop. why original return a Dict and for loop return a set.

Comment: First off: Don't use `list` as a variable name - `list` is a builtin type! Jason gave you the right advice: Replace `future_result = {executor.submit(ping_result, list, 'ping')}` with `future_result[executor.submit(ping_result, list, 'ping')] = list` and you're done. The first version builds the dictionary via a comprehension, the second via a loop. You really should learn basic Python features before fiddling around wiht stuff like `concurrent.futures`.